# maximum and index of multi-dimensional array in Julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to find the max value and index of that value in multidimensional array in Julia. The code is the following:

```
temp = 0
final_A = 1
final_B = 1
final_C = 1
final_D = 1
length = 10

function maxis(final, temp, final_A, final_B, final_C, final_D, final)

for A in 1:length
  for B in 1:length
    for C in 1:length
      for D in 1:length

        final[A, B, C, D] = A + B + C + D

        if final[A, B, C, D] > temp
           temp = final[A, B, C, D]
           final_A = A
           final_B = B
           final_C = C
           final_D = D

        end


      end
    end
  end
end

end
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:** Note, for Julia v0.7+, `indmax` has been deprecated in favour of `argmax`, and for arrays of dimension greater than `1`, `argmax` returns a `CartesianIndex`. This means there is no need to mess around with `ind2sub` anymore, and indeed for this reason, this function has also been deprecated.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:** Some example code that answers the question:

```
julia> x = rand(1:10, 3, 4, 2)
3×4×2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 3  5  3  3
 1  4  9  1
 1  5  9  8

[:, :, 2] =
 2  4  7  3
 1  4  2  4
 5  5  5  5

julia> maximum(x)
9

julia> indmax(x) #returns the linear index
8

julia> ind2sub(x,indmax(x)) #returns the cartesian index as tuple of Int
(2, 3, 1)
```

This will only find the index of the first maximum value in the case of duplicate maximums. However, the sample code you posted appears to do the same thing.

Note also `?CartesianIndex` might be useful reading if you are working with cartesian indices a lot.

Comment: Thank you very much but can you do it with the example that I provided? I am new to this and I do not know the syntax, especially using a function/

Comment: Colin's answer contains all the information you need. If you don't know Julia syntax then it would for example be a good start to read the (well written) [Getting Started](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/getting-started/) section of Julia's documentation.

Comment: @Lvassilopoulos you could combine it into a one-liner using `findmax`: `findmax_multi(x) = let (m, i) = findmax(x); m, ind2sub(x, i) end`. To get more info about functions, open the Julia REPL, and type a question mark. Then the prompt changes to `help?>`, and you can enter the name of functions and types to get information about their usage.

Comment: @Lvassilopoulos On StackOverflow, it is best to stick to one problem per question. If you want to ask something about function syntax, then start a new question for that (although it would be a good idea to read some docs first, as suggested by another commenter). For the problem of finding the index of the maximum value in a multi-dimensional array, I think my answer is complete. If you agree, please mark the question answered by clicking the little green tick next to my response.